# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Product> above this FeedsProduct Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, provider, flutter-provider

im trying to get data that i store inside of my Product.dart module and when i tried to it give me this error

[image]

[image]

this is my feeds_product.dart file

```dart
class FeedsProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedsProduct({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeedsProductState createState() => _FeedsProductState();
}

class _FeedsProductState extends State<FeedsProduct> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productAttribute = Provider.of<Product>(context);
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProductDetailsScreen.routeName);
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
.
.
.
.
.......
```

been tried to change the code but the code only work when the `final productAttribute = Provider.of<Product>(context);` was gone this what it's look like in the screen right now

[image]

this is the my `main.dart` code

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => ThemeNotifier()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => ProductProvider()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(builder: (context, notifier, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: const BottomNavScreen(),
          routes: {
           -----------------------
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the `product.dart` module code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String productCategoryName;
  final String brand;
  final int quantity;
  final bool isFavorite;
  final bool isFreeOngkir;
  final bool isPopular;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.brand,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.isFavorite,
    required this.isFreeOngkir,
    required this.isPopular,
    required this.price,
    required this.productCategoryName,
    required this.quantity,
  });
}

class ProductProvider with ChangeNotifier {

final List<Product> _products = [...
 
  List<Product> products() => _products;

  List<Product> getByCatName(String title) {
    List<Product> titleList = _products
        .where((element) =>
            element.productCategoryName.toLowerCase() == title.toLowerCase())
        .toList();
    return titleList;
  }

  List<Product> getByBrandName(String brandName) {
    List<Product> catList = _products
        .where(
            (element) => element.brand.toLowerCase() == brandName.toLowerCase())
        .toList();
    return catList;
  }

  Product getById(String prodId) {
    return _products.firstWhere((element) => element.id == prodId);
  }

  List<Product> get popularProducts {
    return _products.where((element) => element.isPopular).toList();
  }
}
```

already tried all thing that relate and search for the solution. and i watch some reference that help me but still won't work for it

Comment: can you show the root node code

Comment: @YeasinSheikh done, its in the `main.dart`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ProductProvider` instead of `Product`.

```dart
 final productPorvider= Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context);
```

Comment: nope, won't work. letme put my `Product.dart` code upside

Comment: ok, consider including others widgets and class that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: Can you test update answer

Comment: tried and they say, `The getter 'imageUrl' isn't defined for the type 'ProductProvider'.
Try importing the library that defines 'imageUrl', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'imageUrl'.` and some more same problem in the `Image.network(productAttribute.imageUrl),`

Comment: In order to get imageUrl, you need to get specific product from this provider. let say you like to find by id. in that case do `productPorvider.getById(passId).imageUrl`. you might like passing specific product if it the widget is for product details

Comment: well i trying to get a list of data so i can't specified the id

Comment: you can get list like `productPorvider.products()` also you can convert it as getter like `List<Product> get products=>_products;`